# Throw statement outside of catch statement

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to use throw statement outside of `try{} catch{}` statement? In my code(Plugin programming in CRM 2011) I just want to show a custom message to the user. If throw doesnot work then how can I do that?

any suggestion?

Comment: Yes you can. For example `if(value == null) throw new NullValueException();`

Comment: You should post the error you're getting. I commonly trip myself up (albeit briefly) by not placing the 'new' keyword before the exception (not sure why, I know this is completely silly.) Also, I'm pretty sure the parser will allow throw anywhere a statement is allowed.

Comment: Why didn't you just try if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 7):

To communicate a message back to a user in a plugin you can simply throw an exception

```
throw new Exception("Your message here!");
```

Doesn't have to be in a try/catch block - infact if it was, the message would be suppressed and the user wouldn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, as other answers state here, you can throw an exception and prevent any further action in your plugin. However as you are specifically referring to programming with Dynamics CRM plug-ins, I recommended you only ever throw `InvalidPluginExecutionException` to reflect custom messages to your users as per [MSDN guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334685.aspx).

> You can optionally display a custom error message in a dialog of the
>   Web application by having your plug-in throw an
>   InvalidPluginExecutionException exception with the custom message as
>   the Message property value. It is recommended that plug-ins only pass
>   an InvalidPluginExecutionException back to the platform.

Therefore if you encounter a logical error in your plug-in (eg. Title field is empty) you can:

```
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Title must not be blank");
```

Comment: Good point. I've always wondered why that is - any idea? There is no appreciable difference I have found in using InvalidPluginExecutionException compared to any other Exception derived class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
throw new Exception("your message");
```

or

```
throw new Exception(objectExtendedFromExceptionClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use throw statement outside of try{} catch(){} statement?

Absolutely. The exception will propagate up the stack to the nearest matching catch block. Of course, you will have to have a catch block *somewhere* doing the right thing... but it needn't be in the same method or even the same class.

Whether an exception is the most appropriate solution here is a different matter, of course - it depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

from MSDN : [Throwing Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx)

> Exceptions contain a property named StackTrace. This string contains
>   the name of the methods on the current call stack, together with the
>   file name and line number where the exception was thrown for each
>   method.

yes you can throw exception. like this

```
throw new Exception("Your Error here!");
```